# How to unbind event handler and pass arguments simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following scenario in my code:

```js
function outer() {
  console.log(x);
  //after some time if certain conditions are met remove handler from #red
  $("#red").off("click", outer);
}

function inner() {
  var x = 786;  
  $("#red").click(outer); 
}

inner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">
  RED
</div>
```

The `outer` function cannot be declared inside `inner` function. The example is a simplified version of my actual problem. In my actual problem `inner` function is an `each` which executes on `success` of ajax request. For the code to work I have to pass `x` to `outer` as an argument because `x` is out of scope of `outer`. Then the code would be like:

```js
function outer(x) {
  console.log(x);  
}

function inner() {
  var x = 786; 
  
  $("#red").click(function(){   
    outer(x);
  });
}

inner();
//after some time if certain conditions are met remove handler from #red

$("#red").off("click", outer); // Dosen't work now
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">
  RED
</div>
```

In the first example I could unbind the click handeler but could not pass `x` as argument. In second example I can pass `x` as argument but cannot unbind the event.

- How do I unbind event handler and pass arguments simultaneously? Please also note, I don't want to remove all handlers with `$("#red").off("click")`.

---

I tried using closures but they didn't work too:

```js
function extra(x) {
  function outer(x) {
    console.log(x);

    //after some time if certain conditions are met remove handler from #red
    $("#red").off("click", extra(x)); // Hangs the computer
  }
  return outer;
}


function inner() {
  var x = 786;

  $("#red").click(extra(x));
}

inner();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red">
  RED
</div>
```

Clicking on RED hangs my computer so I could not test this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`.off()` works with `.on()`. So your code could look like this:

```
function outer(x) {
  $('body').append('<br>button clicked and event removed! x value: ' + x);
  $("#red").off(".onlythis");
}

function inner() {
  var x = 786;  
  $("#red").on('click.onlythis', function(){ outer(x); }); 
}

inner();
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xgvjap09/)

[jQuery `.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: But this would remove all click events from `#red`. I want to remove only that specific handler.

Comment: You can use a namespace when you bind the event. I've edited the answer

Comment: Can we use namespaces in plain javascript removeEventListener too?